# Subscript out of range VBA for Workbooks but Open works

Tags: excel, vba

I want my makro to make a reference to another Workbook without open it. I just want to retrieve some data.

```
Sub tm()
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks("C:\Test\test.xlsx")
End Sub
```

But I get "Subscript out of range", but this works fine

```
Sub tm()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test\test.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Why can't I access a Workbook without open it?

Comment: If you don't want to open the workbook, you could just query the workbook. There are plenty of examples on the web on how to do that. But you cannot reference a workbook the way you have without opening it

Comment: Because you can't get into a room without opening the door.  if you want a reference to the book then open the book as in your 2nd example.

Comment: I think this is a good **beginner** question but what would be a good answer. Stating that _a workbook is a member of the workbooks collection and the workbooks collection contains all workbooks currently open in Excel_ would not really help.

Comment: If you want to retrieve data from another workbook you could use this [function](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/)

Comment: @Alex K If you are right my first example should work if I start by opening test.xlsx manually, but that fails too

Comment: In your first example the workbook has already to be open and you have to use only the filename without the path. But in your case this is not neccessary as you opened the file before and have a reference to the workbook. I'd suggest to read [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-workbook/)

Comment: @Storax thanks I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the open, but with this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

in front of the

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test\test.xlsx")
```

plus I would close the document after its use:

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

With these the useage of test.xlsx will not be visible